# Cisco 49XX multicast flooding

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, multicast, troubleshooting

I have problem with multicast on cisco 4948.

I've got vlan 9 with muilticast, which configured on several ports. Switch floods multicast traffic on all ports configured with vlan 9. It consumes link bandwidth.

As far as I know this model doesn't support a IGMP snooping querier, so all multicast floods on all ports with vlan 9. As I understand I need to [enable L3](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/stop-multicast-from-flooding-all-ports/td-p/1116781).

My switch has no routing enabled and no L3 configured at this time, and I try to enable L3 to prevent flooding.

```
conf t
 ip multicast-routing 

 interface Vlan9
  ip address 10.22.0.161 255.255.255.128
  ip pim sparse-mode
  no shutdown
 end
end
```

What else should be configured for getting IGMP snooping to work correctly?

Maybe I can get it to work with some static mapping without enabling L3 on switch?

P.S. Now my switch without L3 and multicast routing enabled, snooping is enabled globally as should by default:

```
catos#show ip igmp snooping vlan 9
Global IGMP Snooping configuration:
-----------------------------------
IGMP snooping             : Enabled
IGMPv3 snooping           : Enabled
Report suppression        : Enabled
TCN solicit query         : Disabled
TCN flood query count     : 2

Vlan 9:
--------
IGMP snooping                       : Enabled
IGMPv2 immediate leave              : Disabled
Explicit host tracking              : Enabled
Multicast router learning mode      : pim-dvmrp
CGMP interoperability mode          : IGMP_ONLY
```

Mrouter is on uplink because I don't have L3 configured now:

```
catos#show ip igmp snooping mrouter 
Vlan    ports
----    -----
 9    Po1(dynamic)
```

Under vlan configuration there are no ip commands at all:

```
catos(config)#vlan 9
catos(config-vlan)#ip?
% Unrecognized command
```

Under interface:

```
catos(config-vlan)#int vl9
catos(config-if)#ip igmp s?           
static-group
```

And the version of software:

```
catos#show version 
Cisco IOS Software, Catalyst 4000 L3 Switch Software (cat4000-I5K91S-M), Version 12.2(25)EWA9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 21-Mar-07 11:58 by tinhuang
Image text-base: 0x10000000, data-base: 0x115C6158

ROM: 12.2(31r)SGA1
Pod Revision 0, Force Revision 34, Tie Revision 20

Catalyst-2 uptime is 8 weeks, 1 hour, 11 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload
System restarted at 11:09:28 EET Tue Dec 4 2018
System image file is "bootflash:cat4000-i5k91s-mz.122-25.EWA9.bin"
...
cisco WS-C4948-10GE (MPC8540) processor (revision 5) with 262144K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FOX1233GZE3
MPC8540 CPU at 667Mhz, Fixed Module
```

Btw, I have another such switch with same problem but with little bit another software:

```
bootflash:cat4500-entservicesk9-mz.122-46.SG.bin"
```

Finally I've updated my switch with rommon by the way:

```
Cisco IOS Software, Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch Software (cat4500-ENTSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SG11, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2016 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 24-Oct-16 09:48 by prod_rel_team
Image text-base: 0x10000000, data-base: 0x123AECA8

ROM: 12.2(31r)SGA7
Pod Revision 0, Force Revision 31, Gill Revision 20

Catalyst-2 uptime is 4 hours, 18 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload
System image file is "bootflash:cat4500-entservicesk9-mz.150-2.SG11.bin"
Last reload reason: Reload command
```

Flooding is still exists now:

```
#show ip igmp snooping vlan 9 detail 
Global IGMP Snooping configuration:
-------------------------------------------
IGMP snooping                : Enabled
IGMPv3 snooping              : Enabled
Report suppression           : Enabled
TCN solicit query            : Disabled
TCN flood query count        : 2
Last Member Query Interval   : 1000

Vlan 9:
--------
IGMP snooping                       : Enabled
CAPWAP enabled                      : Disabled
IGMPv2 immediate leave              : Disabled
Explicit host tracking              : Enabled
Multicast router learning mode      : pim-dvmrp
CGMP interoperability mode          : IGMP_ONLY
Last Member Query Interval          : 1000Topology change                     : No

# show ip igmp snooping mrouter vlan 9 
Vlan    ports
----    -----
   9    Po7(dynamic), Switch

# show ip igmp snooping querier vlan 9 detail 
IP address               : 10.0.0.7
IGMP version             : v2
Port                     : Switch
Max response time        : 10s


Global IGMP switch querier status
--------------------------------------------------------
admin state                    : Enabled
admin version                  : 2
source IP address              : 0.0.0.0        
query-interval (sec)           : 60
max-response-time (sec)        : 10
querier-timeout (sec)          : 120
tcn query count                : 2
tcn query interval (sec)       : 10

Vlan 9:   IGMP switch querier status
--------------------------------------------------------
elected querier is 10.0.0.7       (this switch querier)
--------------------------------------------------------
admin state                    : Enabled (state configured)
admin version                  : 2
source IP address              : 10.0.0.7      
query-interval (sec)           : 60
max-response-time (sec)        : 10
querier-timeout (sec)          : 120
tcn query count                : 2
tcn query interval (sec)       : 10
operational state              : Querier
operational version            : 2
tcn query pending count        : 0

# show ip igmp snooping groups vlan 9 count 
Total number of groups in Vlan 9:   152

# show ip igmp snooping groups vlan 9       
Vlan      Group                    Version     Port List
---------------------------------------------------------
  9       239.1.0.1                v2          Po7
  9       239.1.0.2                v2          Po7
...
  9       239.1.0.253              v2          Po7
  9       239.1.0.254              v2          Po7
  9       239.255.255.250          v2          Po7
```

10.0.0.7 is my switch management address which belongs to local VRF.
[image: Flooding image]

Some mac multicast entries:

```
  #show mac address-table multicast 
Multicast Entries
 vlan    mac address     type    ports
-------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------------
   9    0100.5e01.0001     igmp Po7
   9    0100.5e01.0002     igmp Po7
 ...
   9    0100.5e01.00fe     igmp Po7
   9    0100.5e7f.fffa     igmp Po7
   9    ffff.ffff.ffff   system Gi1/31,Po7
```

Maybe snooping is working, but not as expected. Another vendors doesn't forward traffic if device doesn't need it. And more newer cisco models too.

This is snooping configuration from another cisco 4948 which suffers from the same problem.

```
#show ip igmp snooping vlan 9
Global IGMP Snooping configuration:
-----------------------------------
IGMP snooping              : Enabled
IGMPv3 snooping            : Enabled
Report suppression         : Enabled
TCN solicit query          : Disabled
TCN flood query count      : 2
Last Member Query Interval : 1000

Vlan 9:
--------
IGMP snooping                       : Enabled
IGMPv2 immediate leave              : Disabled
Explicit host tracking              : Enabled
Multicast router learning mode      : pim-dvmrp
Last Member Query Interval          : 1000
CGMP interoperability mode          : IGMP_ONLY

#show mac address-table multicast vlan 9
Multicast Entries
 vlan    mac address     type    ports
-------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------------
   9    0100.5e7f.fffa     igmp Gi1/42,Po5
   9    ffff.ffff.ffff   system Gi1/18,Gi1/22,Gi1/24,Gi1/25,Gi1/26,Gi1/28
                                Gi1/32,Gi1/38,Gi1/39,Gi1/42,Po5
```

If you look ad diagrams traffic burst are absolutly identical, but I do not have such problems on Extreme/EdgeCore devices at all out of the box without configuration.
Green image from one switch, last image from totally different switch:
[image: Traffic Image]

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are trying to do or what you are asking.

Comment: I've correct my question.

Comment: You activate IGMP snooping on the specific vlan by using `conf t` `vlan 9` `ip igmp snooping`. Alternatively you can globally activate IGMP snooping by using `conf t` `ip igmp snooping`. You can check that it's enabled by using `show ip igmp snooping vlan 9`

Comment: What software version are you running? I see catos, that is not good.

Comment: Yes, this is ols switch with System image file is "bootflash:cat4000-i5k91s-mz.122-25.EWA9.bin"

Comment: Please leave output of `show version`

Comment: There is full IGMP support from 12.2(50)SG.

Comment: My suggestion is that you upgrade to the latest version 15.0.2-SG11, which is also a safe harbor software.

Comment: After you've upgraded you will also have access to IGMP snooping querier.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try today and get feedback here. But why people say that 4900 series doesn't support a snooping queerer

Comment: It does, you can see the configuration guide here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/50sg/configuration/guide/Wrapper-46SG/multi.html#wp1163784

Comment: **IGMP Snooping Querier support was introduced in Cisco IOS Release 12.2(50)SG**

Comment: What multicast groups are being flooded?

Comment: I've edit main question, but groups like 239.1.0.1.

Comment: OK. I see groups that are affected by IGMP snooping, but I do not see any evidence that traffic is flooded to other VLAN 9 interfaces. How are you determining that the traffic is flooded to all VLAN 9 interfaces?

Comment: show mac address-table multicast vlan 9; and it shows me ports. On another switch which has many ports with vlan 9 there are Gi1/18,Gi1/22,Gi1/24,Gi1/25,Gi1/26,Gi1/28... Here there is only one active port. And yes you a right - traffic is flooded whether device need it or not in VLAN 9

Comment: Configuring IGMP snooping on one switch does not prevent flooding on other switches. You need to enable it on all switches to which VLAN 9 connects. You only need a querier on a single switch. It looks like IGMP snooping is working on this switch.

Comment: I know that. I mention about another switch only for example. Maybe working, but not as expected. I try to explain.

Comment: I've appended explanations to main post.

Comment: The interfaces seem very limited, so it looks like it is working. Remember that `ffff.ffff.ffff` is the broadcast address, and traffic sent to the broadcast address will be sent everywhere, regardless of IGMP or multicast. Only MAC addresses that start with `0100.5e` are multicast addresses.

Comment: On the first switch, the multicast traffic seems to be only sent to the querier interface (`Po7`), and that is proper. The send switch has two interfaces for a single multicast group, but it looks like a lot of other interfaces are up and receiving broadcasts, so IGMP snooping is preventing multicasts to those interfaces.

Comment: But when add more ports to VLAN 9 they will receive the same amount of traffic. Traffic only floods to all ports which belongs to vlan 9. Looks like I do something wrong but what I don't know. Snooping works by default on most devices but here it works a little bit strange. I've connected the same device to another vendor and it does't receive such multicast frames.

Comment: Are you sure it is multicast traffic? If you have something sending broadcasts, then you cannot control that with IGMP snooping because broadcasts will be flooded to every other interface in the broadcast domain. If added interfaces do not show up in the multicast MAC address table, then they are not getting the multicasts. I think you may be confused about what is happening. There are poorly crafted applications that use broadcast rather than multicast, and I chastise the programmers on [so] for doing that.

Comment: I'll try to investigate more. If I disable snooping there are about 500-600mb of multicast traffic. Maybe this is normal behaviour. I'll try to sniff received traffic once more. I don't have many cisco devices to test operations, But if it is broadcast it will come to all switches of all different vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading to the latest IOS release for the Cisco 4500/4900 series switch, you will have full support for IGMP version 1 and 2, including IGMP Snooping Querier.

IGMP Snooping Querier support was introduced in Cisco IOS Release 12.2(50)SG. This is a Layer 2 feature required to support IGMP snooping in a VLAN where PIM and IGMP are not configured because the multicast traffic does not require routing.

In a network where IP multicast routing is configured, the IP multicast router acts as the IGMP querier by sending general queries. If the IP-multicast traffic in a VLAN only needs to be Layer 2-switched, an IP-multicast router is not required. Without an IP-multicast router on the VLAN, you must configure another switch as the IGMP querier so that it can send queries.

When enabled, the IGMP snooping querier sends out periodic IGMPv2 queries that trigger IGMP report messages from the switch that requests IP multicast traffic. IGMP snooping listens to these IGMP reports to establish appropriate forwarding.

You can configure a switch to generate IGMP queries on a VLAN regardless of whether IP multicast routing is enabled.

The IGMP Snooping Querier feature can be enabled either globally (i.e. they affect every vlan) or on a per-vlan basis.

To configure IGMP Snooping Querier, perform these tasks:

- Step 1

  `Switch# configure terminal` Enters global configuration mode.
- Step 2

  `Switch(config)# [no] ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier` Enables IGMP Snooping Querier.
- Step 3

  `Switch(config)# [no] ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier address abcd` Configures the IGMP Snooping Querier source IP address.
- Step 4

  `Switch(config)# [no] ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier version [1 | 2]` Configures IGMP Snooping Querier IGMP version.
- Step 5

  `Switch(config)# ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier query-interval interval` Configures IGMP Snooping Querier query interval.
- Step 6

  `Switch(config)# ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier max-response-time value` Configures IGMP Snooping Querier query maximum response time.
- Step 7

  `Switch(config)# ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier timer expiry value` Configures IGMP Snooping Querier expiry time out.
- Step 8

  `Switch(config)# ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier tcn query count value` Configures IGMP Snooping Querier tcn query count.
- Step 9

  `Switch(config)# ip igmp snooping  [vlan vlan_id] querier tcn query interval value` Configures IGMP Snooping Querier tcn query interval.
- Step 10

  `Switch(config)# end` Return to privileged EXEC mode.

Full configuration guide from Cisco:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/50sg/configuration/guide/Wrapper-46SG/multi.html#wp1163784

Comment: I've update my IOS to cat4500-entservicesk9-mz.150-2.SG11 with rommon cat4500-ios-promupgrade-122_31r_SGA7. But the behavior is the same. I have enable ip igmp snooping 9 querier.

Comment: Nevertheless thank you for you help very much.

Comment: You need to follow the configuration guide in the link. We have it running in our organization without problems. :-)

Comment: @Tomato  please post show version so that we can see the new version.

Comment: I recognise, I've done only first step. I set IGMP Snooping Querier source IP address but then removed it because I do not see any changes.

Comment: My switch is up to date now - cat4500-entservicesk9-mz.150-2.SG11 with new rom ROM: 12.2(31r)SGA7. Thank you for your advice. 
New show version is in main post.

Comment: @Tomato let me know when you try to fully implement snooping. :-)